# База данных в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, pyqt5

Есть 2 кода. В первом 2 кнопки: список фильмов и список сериалов. Во втором коде база данных со списком фильмов. Помогите объединить эти 2 кода так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку список фильмов, вылазила таблица со списком фильмов(второй код).

Вот первый код:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow


class Films(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.Films_button = QPushButton('список фильмов', self)
        self.Films_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Films_button.move(300, 500)

        self.Serials_button = QPushButton('список сериалов', self)
        self.Serials_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Serials_button.move(300, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Films()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот второй код с базой данных:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('films_db.sqlite')
        db.open()
        view = QTableView(self)
        model = QSqlTableModel(self, db)
        model.setTable('films')
        model.select()

        view.setModel(model)
        view.move(10, 10)
        view.resize(617, 315)

        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 650, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle('Пример')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Вот этот код пытаюсь соединить:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QDialog, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel


class Films(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Films')

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable('films')

        self.view_films = QTableView()
        self.view_films.setModel(self.model)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.view_films)
        
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def refresh(self):
        self.model.select()


class Guitar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('films_db.sqlite')
        self.db.open()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Гитара')

        self.Accords_button = QPushButton('список аккордов', self)
        self.Accords_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Accords_button.move(300, 500)
        self.Accords_button.clicked.connect(self._show_films)

        self.Songs_button = QPushButton('список песен', self)
        self.Songs_button.resize(200, 100)
        self.Songs_button.move(300, 200)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.Accords_button)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.Songs_button)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _show_films(self):
        films = Films(self)
        films.refresh()
        films.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Guitar()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Столько опечаток и код неправильно оформлен. Куда вы так спешите? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объединил виджеты и логику двух виджетов в одном. Для размещения виджетов использовал компоновщик, вместо ручного указания

Попробуйте:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('films_db.sqlite')
        self.db.open()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button_films = QPushButton('список фильмов')
        self.button_films.clicked.connect(self._show_films)

        self.button_serials = QPushButton('список сериалов')

        self.model_films = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)
        self.model_films.setTable('films')

        self.view_films = QTableView()
        self.view_films.setModel(self.model_films)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_films)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_serials)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.view_films)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _show_films(self):
        self.model_films.select()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD.** Открытие в отдельном окне:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableView, QDialog, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel


class Films(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Films')
        
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable('films')

        self.view_films = QTableView()
        self.view_films.setModel(self.model)

        main_layout.addWidget(self.view_films)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def refresh(self):
        self.model.select()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('films_db.sqlite')
        self.db.open()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button_films = QPushButton('список фильмов')
        self.button_films.clicked.connect(self._show_films)

        self.button_serials = QPushButton('список сериалов')

        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_films)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_serials)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _show_films(self):
        films = Films(self)
        films.refresh()
        films.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: программа работает, но я наверно не совсем  уточнил вопрос. Мне не надо чтоб сразу снизу была эта таблица с фильмами. Нужно, чтоб именно по нажатию кнопки, открывалось так сказать новое окно, и там уже была одна эта таблица. Так получиться сделать?

Comment: @INdigrID, такие нюансы нужно сразу описывать :) получится. Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, вроде помогло, пока не совсем разобрался, как всё работает. Но если что, я думаю вам напишу, если будут какие то вопросы

Comment: Ага, спрашивайте тут, если это относится к теме вопроса или моего кода :)

Comment: лучше другой создать, чтоб вы репутации еще получили

Comment: Спасибо, но консультацию по моему ответу, лучше тут и провести :) А вот по другим вопросам или по доработке кода --  в новых вопросах ;)

Comment: а на этом сайте нет, что-то типо личных сообщений?

Comment: Неа. А вы стесняетесь задавать вопросы, думая что они слишком новичковые? :) А зря

Comment: просто, небольшие проблемы. Ну типо, да)

Comment: у меня есть другой похожий код, я пытался сделать на примере вашего, но ничего не поулчается

Comment: @INdigrID, напишите подробнее в чем ошибка и покажите пример кода (pastebin или github gists) с проблемой

Comment: в этом вопросе или в новом?

Comment: Да прямо тут, в комментарии. Глянуть не сложно, если там какая-то муторная муть, то можно и как вопрос оформить, чтобы было удобно с этим разбираться и после ответить

Comment: Вот мой код, и я пытаюсь обьединить его с  вашим, но ничего не выходит

Comment: я его добавил в вопрос

Comment: мне нужно чтоб тоже самое окно вылезало по нажатию кнопки список песен, пытался как мог. Не даётся. Мне еще надо чтоб размеры, и названия окна остались незименны

Comment: Непонятно что вы хотите сделать с Guitar, т.е. причем оно тут вообще. Не вижу тут связи с предыдущими окнами :) Если это сложно объяснить, сделайте отдельный вопрос :D

Comment: Guitar(не обращайте внимания на навзвание) класс. Есть 2 клавиши список аккордов и список песен, у меня пока вместо песен фильмы. Нужно чтб в этом классе, вот как всё сейчас есть у меня в коде, по нажатию клавиши список песен, открывалась та таблица с фильмами, ну, а с аккордами я по аналогии сдлелаю

Comment: Ну делаете аналогично: сделайте метод, пусть будет, `_show_films` в нем тот же код, что в ответе, а кнопку `self.Songs_button` подключаете к методу через сигнал `clicked`. Этот код `self.button_films.clicked.connect(self._show_films)` говорит, что у кнопки есть сигнал `clicked`, который вызывается при клике на кнопку и мы к этому сигналу подключаем метод `_show_films`

Comment: не получилось что-то чуть чуть, я добавил, самый последний код, можете запустить посмотреть? Как мне убрать вот эти растянутые кнопки на заднем плане?

Comment: Вы в Guitar два раза вызываете `self.initUI()` и не используйте у виджетов `move` и `resize` если виджеты размещаете на компоновщики -- они как раз сами и занимаются расположением и размером виджетов. Размеры виджетов в компоновщиках можно дополнительно менять через setMinimal/setMaximal/setFixed/setSizePolicy, стандартное поведение виджетов и так нормальное, поэтому это не редко требуется

Comment: если убираю self.initUI() остаются только кнопки растянутые, которые были на заднем плане, а мне наоборот, надо их убрать

Comment: @INdigrID, у вас два раза вызывается initUI это явно неправильно, а те что растянутые, это потому что они находятся в компоновщике, как писал выше вы можете его настроить. Либо использовать другой компоновщик типа QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout или QFormLayout. И я рекомендую использовать их благодаря их адаптации к изменению размеров окон и автоматическому размещение

Comment: А насчет расположения кнопок. Скорее всего дело так: при первом вызове кнопки размещаются на компоновщике и растянутые, хоть и им указали явно их размеры и положение, а при повторном вызове создались еще кнопки с таким же поведением и снова был установлен компоновщик, а предыдущий перестал контролировать кнопки и они встали где им указали в move и с размером как resize. Если вам не нужен компоновщик, то уберите его из кода

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116411/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red----pyqt5).